# Julia: packaging things into modules vs include()-ing them

Tags: julia

I'm building a simulation in Julia and I have my code split across a bunch of files. Are there any benefits to wrapping everything in modules versus simplying `include()`-ing them in the runscript?

I have something like the following at the top of my runscript right now:

```
for filename in split(readall(`git ls-files`))
    @everywhere include(filename)
end
```

I'm not planning to use the code outside of this immediate project, but I am running the simulation in parallel. Is there any benefit in creating modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the most important benefit is modularity :)
If you have different files that deal with different things, splitting the code into modules let's you keep track on the dependencies between the modules:

- Which functions are purely implementation details of the given module and subject to change?
- Which modules depend on which other modules?

It also lets you reuse the same name for different things in the different modules if you need to, if you're a little careful of what you export. (You can still access those names from the outside as qualified names)

For an example of such organisation, you can look at my repo https://github.com/toivoh/Debug.jl