# Using julia in a cluster

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing, julia

I've been using Julia in parallel on my computer successfully but want to increase the number of processors/workers I use so I plan to use my departmental cluster (UCL Econ). When just using julia on my computer, I have two seperate files. FileA contains all the functions I use, including the main function funcy(x,y,z). FileB calls this function over several processors as follows:

```
addprocs(4)
require("FileA.jl")
solution = pmap(imw ->  funcy(imw,y,z), 1:10)
```

When I try to run this on the cluster, the require statement does not seem to work (though I don't get an explicit error output which is frustrating). Any advice?

Comment: does the issue go away if you replace `require` with `include`?

Comment: Kevin - it did not, sadly!

Comment: It will be better for others to help you If you can make your code replicable.

Comment: Could you please post the error that the require statement causes? It is difficult to debug without a clear error message.

Comment: As far as I know, Julia doesn't copy additional files (linked by `include` or `require`) automatically to all hosts in a cluster, so remote processes just don't know where to find your `FileA.jl`. To make this code work, you should either prepend each statement in `FileA.jl` with `@everywhere` macro, or copy the file to each machine (e.g. upload via ssh before running the process or deploying within a package).

Comment: ffriend - Yes I thought it was generic problem with my use of require (hence why I have not included detailed code). I have now tried putting all functions in the same file and pre-fixing with the "@everywhere" macro. I also need to broadcast  parameters to all nodes so I pre-fix them with "@eval @everywhere", and I try to make sure all nodes are using the correct  packages with "@everywhere using PkgA". But I now get the error output: "julia: /lib64/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /cm/shared/apps/Julia/0.3.1/bin/../lib/julia/libjulia.so)".

Comment: as a corollary to @ffriend's answer, consider stuffing your code into a module (say, `MyModule`) and then calling `using MyModule` after `addprocs(4)`. That *should* correct the problem that you observe. The wrinkle is that you need the module installed on whatever shared Julia instance your UCL Econ cluster uses. You may need to be super chummy with your sysadmin for this route to work X-(.

Comment: see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36993846/julia-packaging-things-into-modules-vs-include-ing-them) as a related point.